# DW_OP_fbreg 'operand' to retrieve value of a variable is not working as expected?

Tags: debugging

Setup: I am debugging a simple C++ program compiled with option -fno-omit-frame-pointer, using libwarf for DWARF 5. Main work is to write a debugger using libdwarf.

For a particular local variable, dwarfdump shows:

DW_AT_location              len 0x0002: 915c: DW_OP_fbreg -36

In the following I will refer to '-36' as 'op1', which I get from libdwarf.

---

Problem: Using op1 directly results in incorrect value for the variable.
(fbPointer is current value of frame base pointer).

```
int32_t data = (int32_t) ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, processPid, fbPointer + op1, 0);
```

I also tried decoding -36 as sleb128 and usleb128, and for both I got 220. Not a good value.

Trial/error shows that if I add 16 to op1, it will work for any number of int variables as parameters and local objects. However, it does not work for float/double.

---

Question: Is -36, as mentioned everywhere, offset of variable from frame-base pointer? If so, what am I doing wrong?
What are the preceding values in DW_AT_location: "len 0x0002: 915c:"? If they are important in evaluating op1, how do I get them via libdwart?

Thank you very much. It has been more than a week I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DW_OP_fbreg is a reference to DWARF register which in this case is 16 bytes off. That is, we need to add 16 to RBP, the real register, then add -36 to that. Finally, somehow in this case -36 is a plain number as opposed to encoded sleb128.